# Faulty cursor location during pydev interactive session in ECLIPSE

Tags: python, eclipse, ubuntu, cursor, pydev

I am using the Latest Eclipse (3.7.0) with Pydev. The problem I am facing is that when I use interactive mode my cursor location is totally weird and very frustrating.

The cursor is never located after >>> and sometimes I have to press enter to bring the cursor on next line as it will be on result from last line.

But IDLE3 works fine and locates cursor at right position. Therefore I think there is some problem with PyDev or Eclipse

Is it a bug? or I missed something. I have started to use Eclipse as I want to get along with it which is good for me in long run.

Details: 
OS : Ubuntu 11.10
Python : 3.2
Interactive mode: Run as external tool

Atul Kakrana

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're running it as an external tool... The proper way to have an interactive console in PyDev would be using the interactive console that's builtin into PyDev. See: http://pydev.org/manual_adv_interactive_console.html for details on starting / using that console.